# Get the total number of elements in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

The code outputs the "url" for every "image" ok (up the the limit of 8) with $sep after each url.

But I want to setup a condition that if it finds eg 4 "image"  then it will output $sep 4 times (after printing out 4 urls with $sep after each one). But when I tried the code below it does not seem to be counting the image/images as the count is always 1 (no matter how many "images" there are).

Example xml input

```
<images>
  <image>
   <url>Url</url>
  </image>
  <image>
   <url>Url</url>
  </image>
  <image>
   <url>Url</url>
  </image>
  <image>
   <url>Url</url>
  </image>
</images>
```

XSL code

```
<xsl:for-each select="images/image[position() &lt;= 8]">
    <xsl:value-of select="url"/>    <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />

</xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:variable name="set" select="images/image" />
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count='4'">
         <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

current output

```
URl,URl,URl,URl,
```

wanted output

```
URl,URl,URl,URl,,,,,
```

Thanks

Comment: @H. Pauwelyn Your edit to the question title does not make sense at all, so I rolled back. To the OP: Please show a complete, minimal example of the input document, the stylesheet and the output. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed off the `$` sign when checking the `count` variable. It should be this...

```
<xsl:when test="$count=4">
```

(No need for apostrophes around the 4 either, as $count is a number, although it should still work in XSLT 1.0)

EDIT: Consider using a recursive template to cope with any number of `image` elements in your XSLT.

Try this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="sep" select="','" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="images/image[position() &lt;= 8]">
            <xsl:value-of select="url"/>    <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />

        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:variable name="set" select="images/image" />
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />

        <xsl:call-template name="pad">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="pad">
        <xsl:param name="count" />
        <xsl:if test="$count + 1 &lt; 8">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
            <xsl:call-template name="pad">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```